# Terraform populating a resource via json containing a nested map

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to loop over the json file to populate my `aiven_kafka_topic` resource.

My attempt is below. But, I'm having issues with the `dynamic` config block.
`Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first argument.`

config is an optional map of key=value pairs

```json
{
  "topics": [
      {
          "name": "elvis",
          "partitions": 1,
          "replicas": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "chuck",
          "partitions": 24,
          "replicas": 7,
          "config": {
            "entry_one": "foo",
            "entry_two": "bar"
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

```
locals {
  topics = jsondecode(file(var.topics_config))["topics"]
}

output "locals_topics" {
  value = local.topics
}

resource "aiven_kafka_topic" "this" {
  for_each = { for topic in local.topics : topic.name => topic }

  project      = var.project_name
  service_name = var.kafka_service_name

  topic_name  = each.value.name
  partitions  = each.value.partitions
  replication = each.value.replicas

  dynamic "config" {
    for_each = each.value.config

    content {
      # config.key = config.value
      entry_one = lookup(config.key, "entry_one", null)
      entry_two = lookup(config.key, "entry_two", null)
      # etc ...
    }
  }

}
```

Comment:  I don't see any call to `lookup` in the code example you shared. Are you sure you shared the complete example you tried?

Comment: Updated. I had started with lookup but that didn't work

Comment: Really what I want is to convert the config map from the json file and use as the config for the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data structure has exactly one `config` object per topic object, so you don't need a `dynamic` block for your `config` block in the resource:

```
resource "aiven_kafka_topic" "this" {
  for_each = { for topic in local.topics : topic.name => topic }

  project      = var.project_name
  service_name = var.kafka_service_name

  topic_name  = each.value.name
  partitions  = each.value.partitions
  replication = each.value.replicas

  config {
    cleanup_policy   = try(each.value.config.cleanup_policy, null)
    compression_type = try(each.value.config.compression_type, null)
    # ...
  }
}
```

The reason for the error you saw in your first attempt is that the `dynamic "config"` block was instructing Terraform to generate one `config` block per element in the config object, and so `config.key` in that block was an individual config item and `config.value` was that item's value, which is a string and therefore not compatible with `lookup`.

My new example above just uses the single `config` object directly, without repeating over its elements, so the result will have only a single `config` block whose arguments may or may not be set depending on whether the corresponding attributes are set in your source object.